# Angular + Material - How to add custom columns in a table (Mat-Table)

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do you add a custom column in a mat table.

Such as adding an edit column containing an edit icon with a click event containing the id of the current element.

```xml
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Color Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Comment: You pasted the wrong plnkr link.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On your TableBasicExample.ts add

```ts
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'customColumn1'];
  dataSource = new ExampleDataSource();
}
```

And in your html file add the column:

```xml
<ng-container matColumnDef="customColumn1">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Custom Title</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Important to note here is the `*matHeaderCellDef`. It having no argument means that you have no column or key to assign to it and thus you can use it as a custom column e.g. for actions. Not putting it there would raise errors.

Comment: Not seeing any difference with *matHeaderCellDef here

Comment: Actually I have to add a column on which if we click, it should not affect the checkbox. Could you please suggest

Answer (score 16):

Here is the one way to do it. It might help someone down the road.

**table.html**

```html
    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef>
           <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef"></ng-container>
       </td>
   </ng-container>
```

**table.component**

```html
 @Input() templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**table-parent.html**

```html
<app-data-table [dataSource]="dataSource" [templateRef]="template">
   <ng-template #template>
      <button mat-icon-button color="warn">
         <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
         <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
      </button>
   </ng-template>
</app-data-table>
```

Hope that saves someone couple hours of search :)

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to achieve is also made in this package [angular4-material-table](http://www.npmjs.com/angular4-material-table), which add some structure to allow row insertion, edition and deletion. You have an example to add custom actions columns on this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6raFTuv7igsuxi7yOVCg?p=preview).

You can define a column with your desired buttons/actions:

```xml
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="column1"> 
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> column 1 title </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <!-- col 1 -->
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container> 
    <ng-container matColumnDef="column2"> 
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> column 2 title </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <!-- col 2 -->
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actionsColumn">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <button (click)="createNew()">Create new</button>
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <button (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
            <button (click)="cancelOrDelete()">Cancel</button>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
    </mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

You must include the column in the displayedColumns string array:

```js
displayedColumns = ['column1', 'column2', 'actionsColumn'];
```

Comment: Hi there [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6raFTuv7igsuxi7yOVCg?p=preview) link you shared is not working.

Answer (score 5):

To add an extra column for your buttons/actions, you first need to add that column to the displayed columns list in the component:

```js
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'customColumn'];
```

and then add an extra column in the html and place your button inside mat-cell:

```xml
    <ng-container matColumnDef="customColumn">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let person"> 
          <button mat-button>Edit</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

And it's done. It is that easy.

Comment: Wildly underrated answer! Thanks, it was super helpful.